# Customize Strip element

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have one <IbanElement> and was wondering to change it style, to make it look like the other inputs  with a label floating that I have on my form. The thing is that I want to add border to the component but it seems impossible. It seems that I have to create a div to include the IbanElement inside the div. Is it the only way?

```
         <InputController>
          <InputLabel>
            <TopLabel show />
            <Elements
              stripe={stripePromise}
              options={{ appearance: { theme: 'night', labels: 'floating' } }}
            >
              <IbanElement options={ibanElementOptions} onChange={onIbanChange} />
            </Elements>
            {ibanError ? (
              <FieldError>{ibanError}</FieldError>
            ) : (
              <LabelText>The IBAN of the bank account that we’ll automatically debit</LabelText>
            )}
          </InputLabel>
        </InputController>
```

Tried to use this but it's the only documentation I got https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api#theme

```
const appearance = {
theme: 'night',
labels: 'floating'
};

// Pass the appearance object to the Elements instance
const elements = stripe.elements({clientSecret, appearance});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Appearance API doesn't support individual payment method elements (called out in the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/appearance-api)). However, you can use a [`style` object](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=iban#elements_create-options-style) with IBAN Element.